# Other phrases for "burst through the door"

Tags: expressions, verbs, phrase-requests

I'm writing a story and I want my character to burst through the door, not literally through the door, however, I didn't want to use the phrase "burst through the door" but am stuck as to another phrase or perhaps verb to use instead. Any suggestions?

Comment: *barged in* is pretty common (offered as a comment instead of an answer because I don't feel two words is substantive enough to warrant an official answer).

Comment: @DanBron thank you, it was something along those lines I was looking for. You've been a help to me.

Comment: He "stormed through the door" (or "stormed into the room").

Answer (score 6):

*[He erupted through the door](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=erupted%20through%20the%20door%2Cerupted%20from%20the%20door&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cerupted%20through%20the%20door%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cerupted%20from%20the%20door%3B%2Cc0)*, borrowing from *The Brothers Piggett* in *[Two Tales Dark and Grim](https://books.google.com/books?id=544kAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT27&dq=%22erupted%20through%20the%20door%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7HCEVeEPx7WxBMzIrpAN&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22erupted%20through%20the%20door%22&f=false)* by Christine Johnson *et al*--literally through the wood:

> *Flinging himself to the window, he wrenched up the frame, just as the wolf's head erupted through the door, snarling and terrible.*

Or from *[The Dancing Boy](https://books.google.com/books?id=UGEhoQ4BSh8C&pg=PT7&dq=%22erupted%20through%20the%20door%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4nCEVYvWFLX7sAS964eACg&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22erupted%20through%20the%20door%22&f=false)* by Ishani Kar Purkayastha--figuratively through the opening:

> *As the monsoon clouds erupted, ma erupted through the door into
>   Moyur's room.*

---

From the perspective of someone already in the room it might be said:

*He **[erupted](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/erupt)** from the door*

Comment: +1.. IMO..more picturesque than exploded..and my last vote.

Comment: I am honored to receive such a precious commodity :-) @Mysti

Comment: @ScotM..precious-- no, not for you. You wield your sword well.

Answer (score 4):

A picturesque alternative is: *He [**exploded**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/explode?q=exploded) through the door!*

Answer (score 4):

'He **bulldozed** his way in through the door...'

From: **bulldoze** (*verb without object*):

> Use force insensitively when dealing with (someone or something).
>           *Source*: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com)
>
> To advance or force one's way in the manner of a [bulldozer](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bulldozer?s=t).
>   *Source*: [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com)

Answer (score 2):

Your characters "**crashed**" through that door!

> [**crashed**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/crash) verb crashed, crashing, crashes:
>   **1**. **a**. To break violently or noisily; smash: The dishes crashed to pieces on the floor. **b**. To undergo sudden damage or destruction on impact: The car **crashed** into a tree. see, the Free Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

> **hastened/ muscled in.**

(vocabulary.com)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

[shot through the door](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=M0b7O4JPEwUC&pg=PT50&dq=%22shot%20through%20the%20door%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BHWEVd6DEoSSuATsyIvYBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22shot%20through%20the%20door%22&f=false)

**[shoot](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/shoot)**:

> 5. [intransitive, transitive] to move suddenly or quickly in one direction; to make somebody/something move in this way (Oxford)

PS - A little context is needed to clarify you're not talking about guns.